# WiFi gets jammed in "turning off" state

Tags: android, wifi, milestone, x10

Hi 
I am developing an application for controlling the WiFi interface and 
I have found a problem: WiFi interface gets jammed on the Xperia X10 
Mini (I tested on three devices of the same model). 
Looking at the log with "logcat" I found the following error:

```
E/wpa_supplicant( 1775): ERROR - wpa_driver_tista_private_send - (ioctl_cmd = 8021501,  res = 1, errno = 99) 
E/wpa_supplicant( 1775): ERROR - Failed to do tista scan! 
W/wpa_supplicant( 1775): Failed to initiate AP scan.
```

The only way to fix the problem is rebooting the device (and it did 
not even work all the times). Has anyone got a solution? Any help is 
welcome?

P.S: I know there is a bug reported here: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9677. However, it is for Motorola Droid, not for Xperia X10 Mini.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it solved. The problem was I was trying to keep the WiFi up but the phone was putting it down when it went to sleep. The result of this procedure is undetermined.

The solution is to acquire a WifiLock:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.WifiLock.html

Comment: Just to complete: I remember WinMo is used to show the same behaviour. Wifi is always turned off during standby but HSDPA is not :) even if they both consume lots of power